# Nested bool query with multiple must and should

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Look at my use case below

Two nested fields

```
base1.point1
base1.point2
base1.point3
base1.point4
```

and

```
base2.point1
base2.point2
base2.point3
base2.point4
```

search condition

```
(
  (base1.point1 AND base1.point2) OR (base1.point2 AND base1.point3)
)
AND
(
  (base2.point1 AND base2.point2) OR (base2.point2 AND base2.point3)
)
```

Please help for writing above in a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I'm assuming that when you meant nested you are actually talking about [Nested Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and not plain [Object Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html)

Also looking at your question, you are only concerned if the nested fields exists or not, regardless of their values. For such use cases you would need to make use of [Exists Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html).

Below is how my [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) would be:

```
POST <you_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "bool":{  
                  "should":[  
                     {  
                        "bool":{  
                           "must":[  
                              {  
                                 "nested":{  
                                    "path":"base1",
                                    "query":{  
                                       "exists":{  
                                          "field":"base1.point1"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              },
                              {  
                                 "nested":{  
                                    "path":"base1",
                                    "query":{  
                                       "exists":{  
                                          "field":"base1.point2"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "bool":{  
                           "must":[  
                              {  
                                 "nested":{  
                                    "path":"base1",
                                    "query":{  
                                       "exists":{  
                                          "field":"base1.point2"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              },
                              {  
                                 "nested":{  
                                    "path":"base1",
                                    "query":{  
                                       "exists":{  
                                          "field":"base1.point3"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {  
               "bool":{  
                  "should":[  
                     {  
                        "bool":{  
                           "must":[  
                              {  
                                 "nested":{  
                                    "path":"base2",
                                    "query":{  
                                       "exists":{  
                                          "field":"base2.point1"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              },
                              {  
                                 "nested":{  
                                    "path":"base1",
                                    "query":{  
                                       "exists":{  
                                          "field":"base2.point2"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "bool":{  
                           "must":[  
                              {  
                                 "nested":{  
                                    "path":"base2",
                                    "query":{  
                                       "exists":{  
                                          "field":"base2.point2"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              },
                              {  
                                 "nested":{  
                                    "path":"base2",
                                    "query":{  
                                       "exists":{  
                                          "field":"base2.point3"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!